# asp.NET Dynamic Button Server Side Event Don't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

i need to make a button for each row in my table in asp.NET.
I cycled my datareader and create manually a "input" button. The problem is that when i click on the button in my page it don't call the Event (btnLogin_ServerClick).

How i can fix?

sorry for my bad english.. I past the code below:

```
    int tmp = 0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        myTable += "<tr>";

        for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            myTable += "<td>";
            myTable += dr[i].ToString();
            myTable += "</td>";
        }

        myTable += "<td>";

         myTable += "<input class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg outline\" type=\"button\" runat=\"server\" value=\"More\" name=\"btn" + tmp + "\" id=\"btnLogin" + tmp+ "\" onserverclick=\"btnLogin_ServerClick\" usesubmitbehavior=\"false\" />"; 
        myTable += "</td>";


        myTable += "</tr>";
        tmp++;
    }


    //--------------------
    //create dynamic table
    //--------------------
    server_badge.InnerText = tmp + "";
    servers_table.InnerHtml = myTable;
}

protected void btnLogin_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("test");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Instead of adding an HTML snippet use the `Button` class. You will obtain the exact same HTML result but on the code-behind you use an actual object, not a string:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.CssClass = "btn btn-primary";
// and so on ...
```

The `Button` class has a property for every imaginable HTML property you may want to configure. You'll find a lot of members, just ignore those who sound outlandish and stick to those that sound like what you need (`CssClass`, `Click`, `OnClientClick` and such). Once you have assigned all the stuff you need (which was in your HTML) you can finally attach an event listener:

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(btnLogin_ServerClick);
          ^ press <TAB> here
```

Visual Studio will generate the handler method when you press `<TAB>` after the `+=` and wrap it into a proper event handler object.